# How to parse Lua table that has a strange structure using C#?

Tags: c#, lua, world-of-warcraft

I would like to parse a file which only contains a table that was saved using Lua, however, while the information is logical (easy to understand what it is for), the storage concept makes it very difficult using conventional Lua parsing strategies.

For example, this is a snip from one part of the structure:

```
["Bag-3"] = {
    ["ids"] = {
        2589, -- [1]
        108996, -- [2]
        4306, -- [3]
        2453, -- [4]
        108330, -- [5]
        2450, -- [6]
        4337, -- [7]
        2592, -- [8]
        108326, -- [9]
        6470, -- [10]
        1529, -- [11]
        4338, -- [12]
        3404, -- [13]
        3685, -- [14]
        108325, -- [15]
        108324, -- [16]
        7067, -- [17]
        785, -- [18]
        5503, -- [19]
        5504, -- [20]
        7069, -- [21]
        5500, -- [22]
        108323, -- [23]
        12662, -- [24]
        53010, -- [25]
        62791, -- [26]
        76061, -- [27]
        74866, -- [28]
        120945, -- [29]
        109131, -- [30]
        111557, -- [31]
        30817, -- [32]
        89112, -- [33]
        30183, -- [34]
        23572, -- [35]
        36931, -- [36]
        34057, -- [37]
        43102, -- [38]
        74249, -- [39]
        72120, -- [40]
        79010, -- [41]
        72092, -- [42]
        72094, -- [43]
        72103, -- [44]
        102542, -- [45]
        102543, -- [46]
        102541, -- [47]
        72163, -- [48]
        36925, -- [49]
        36919, -- [50]
        36928, -- [51]
        36934, -- [52]
        21877, -- [53]
        12205, -- [54]
        10285, -- [55]
        3356, -- [56]
        [97] = 72988,
        [95] = 82441,
        [96] = 72988,
        [98] = 72988,
    },
    ["links"] = {
        "|cffffffff|Hitem:2589:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:100:264:0:0:0|h[Linen Cloth]|h|r", -- [1]
        "|cff1eff00|Hitem:108996:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:100:264:0:0:0|h[Alchemical Catalyst]|h|r", -- [2]
        "|cffffffff|Hitem:4306:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:100:264:0:0:0|h[Silk Cloth]|h|r", -- [3]
        "|cffffffff|Hitem:2453:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:100:264:0:0:0|h[Bruiseweed]|h|r", -- [4]
        "|cffffffff|Hitem:108330:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:100:264:0:0:0|h[Stranglekelp Blade]|h|r", -- [5]
        "|cffffffff|Hitem:2450:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:100:264:0:0:0|h[Briarthorn]|h|r", -- [6]
        "|cffffffff|Hitem:4337:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:100:264:0:0:0|h[Thick Spider's Silk]|h|r", -- [7]
        "|cffffffff|Hitem:2592:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:100:264:0:0:0|h[Wool Cloth]|h|r", -- [8]
        "|cffffffff|Hitem:108326:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:100:264:0:0:0|h[Khadgar's Whisker Stem]|h|r", -- [9]
        "|cffffffff|Hitem:6470:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:100:264:0:0:0|h[Deviate Scale]|h|r", -- [10]
        "|cff1eff00|Hitem:1529:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:100:264:0:0:0|h[Jade]|h|r", -- [11]
        "|cffffffff|Hitem:4338:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:100:264:0:0:0|h[Mageweave Cloth]|h|r", -- [12]
        "|cffffffff|Hitem:3404:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:100:264:0:0:0|h[Buzzard Wing]|h|r", -- [13]
        "|cffffffff|Hitem:3685:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:100:264:0:0:0|h[Raptor Egg]|h|r", -- [14]
        "|cffffffff|Hitem:108325:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:100:264:0:0:0|h[Liferoot Stem]|h|r", -- [15]
        "|cffffffff|Hitem:108324:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:100:264:0:0:0|h[Kingsblood Petal]|h|r", -- [16]
        "|cffffffff|Hitem:7067:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:100:264:0:0:0|h[Elemental Earth]|h|r", -- [17]
        "|cffffffff|Hitem:785:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:100:264:0:0:0|h[Mageroyal]|h|r", -- [18]
        "|cffffffff|Hitem:5503:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:100:264:0:0:0|h[Clam Meat]|h|r", -- [19]
        "|cffffffff|Hitem:5504:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:100:264:0:0:0|h[Tangy Clam Meat]|h|r", -- [20]
        "|cffffffff|Hitem:7069:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:100:264:0:0:0|h[Elemental Air]|h|r", -- [21]
        "|cff1eff00|Hitem:5500:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:100:264:0:0:0|h[Iridescent Pearl]|h|r", -- [22]
        "|cffffffff|Hitem:108323:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:100:264:0:0:0|h[Wild Steelbloom Petal]|h|r", -- [23]
        "|cff1eff00|Hitem:12662:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:100:264:0:0:0|h[Demonic Rune]|h|r", -- [24]
        "|cffffffff|Hitem:53010:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:100:264:0:0:0|h[Embersilk Cloth]|h|r", -- [25]
        "|cffffffff|Hitem:62791:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:100:264:0:0:0|h[Blood Shrimp]|h|r", -- [26]
        "|cff0070dd|Hitem:76061:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:100:264:0:0:0|h[Spirit of Harmony]|h|r", -- [27]
        "|cffffffff|Hitem:74866:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:100:264:0:0:0|h[Golden Carp]|h|r", -- [28]
        "|cff1eff00|Hitem:120945:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:100:264:0:0:0|h[Primal Spirit]|h|r", -- [29]
        "|cffffffff|Hitem:109131:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:100:264:0:0:0|h[Raw Clefthoof Meat]|h|r", -- [30]
        "|cffffffff|Hitem:111557:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:100:264:0:0:0|h[Sumptuous Fur]|h|r", -- [31]
        "|cffffffff|Hitem:30817:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:100:264:0:0:0|h[Simple Flour]|h|r", -- [32]
        "|cffffffff|Hitem:89112:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:100:264:0:0:0|h[Mote of Harmony]|h|r", -- [33]
        "|cffa335ee|Hitem:30183:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:100:264:0:0:0|h[Nether Vortex]|h|r", -- [34]
        "|cff0070dd|Hitem:23572:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:100:264:0:0:0|h[Primal Nether]|h|r", -- [35]
        "|cffa335ee|Hitem:36931:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:100:264:0:0:0|h[Ametrine]|h|r", -- [36]
        "|cffa335ee|Hitem:34057:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:100:264:0:0:0|h[Abyss Crystal]|h|r", -- [37]
        "|cff0070dd|Hitem:43102:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:100:264:0:0:0|h[Frozen Orb]|h|r", -- [38]
        "|cffffffff|Hitem:74249:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:100:264:0:0:0|h[Spirit Dust]|h|r", -- [39]
        "|cffffffff|Hitem:72120:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:100:264:0:0:0|h[Exotic Leather]|h|r", -- [40]
        "|cffffffff|Hitem:79010:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:100:264:0:0:0|h[Snow Lily]|h|r", -- [41]
        "|cffffffff|Hitem:72092:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:100:264:0:0:0|h[Ghost Iron Ore]|h|r", -- [42]
        "|cff1eff00|Hitem:72094:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:100:264:0:0:0|h[Black Trillium Ore]|h|r", -- [43]
        "|cff1eff00|Hitem:72103:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:100:264:0:0:0|h[White Trillium Ore]|h|r", -- [44]
        "|cff1eff00|Hitem:102542:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:100:264:0:0:0|h[Ancient Pandaren Spices]|h|r", -- [45]
        "|cff1eff00|Hitem:102543:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:100:264:0:0:0|h[Aged Mogu'shan Cheese]|h|r", -- [46]
        "|cff1eff00|Hitem:102541:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:100:264:0:0:0|h[Aged Balsamic Vinegar]|h|r", -- [47]
        "|cff0070dd|Hitem:72163:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:100:264:0:0:0|h[Magnificent Hide]|h|r", -- [48]
        "|cffa335ee|Hitem:36925:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:100:264:0:0:0|h[Majestic Zircon]|h|r", -- [49]
        "|cffa335ee|Hitem:36919:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:100:264:0:0:0|h[Cardinal Ruby]|h|r", -- [50]
        "|cffa335ee|Hitem:36928:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:100:264:0:0:0|h[Dreadstone]|h|r", -- [51]
        "|cffa335ee|Hitem:36934:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:100:264:0:0:0|h[Eye of Zul]|h|r", -- [52]
        "|cffffffff|Hitem:21877:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:100:264:0:0:0|h[Netherweave Cloth]|h|r", -- [53]
        "|cffffffff|Hitem:12205:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:100:264:0:0:0|h[White Spider Meat]|h|r", -- [54]
        "|cffffffff|Hitem:10285:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:100:264:0:0:0|h[Shadow Silk]|h|r", -- [55]
        "|cffffffff|Hitem:3356:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:100:264:0:0:0|h[Kingsblood]|h|r", -- [56]
        [97] = "|cffffffff|Hitem:72988:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:100:264:0:0:0|h[Windwool Cloth]|h|r",
        [95] = "|cffffffff|Hitem:82441:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:100:264:0:0:0|h[Bolt of Windwool Cloth]|h|r",
        [96] = "|cffffffff|Hitem:72988:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:100:264:0:0:0|h[Windwool Cloth]|h|r",
        [98] = "|cffffffff|Hitem:72988:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:100:264:0:0:0|h[Windwool Cloth]|h|r",
    },
    ["counts"] = {
        51, -- [1]
        5, -- [2]
        76, -- [3]
        9, -- [4]
        10, -- [5]
        8, -- [6]
        2, -- [7]
        28, -- [8]
        41, -- [9]
        nil, -- [10]
        nil, -- [11]
        nil, -- [12]
        5, -- [13]
        5, -- [14]
        28, -- [15]
        76, -- [16]
        nil, -- [17]
        3, -- [18]
        10, -- [19]
        8, -- [20]
        2, -- [21]
        nil, -- [22]
        53, -- [23]
        nil, -- [24]
        8, -- [25]
        5, -- [26]
        nil, -- [27]
        10, -- [28]
        16, -- [29]
        nil, -- [30]
        nil, -- [31]
        20, -- [32]
        128, -- [33]
        9, -- [34]
        nil, -- [35]
        2, -- [36]
        nil, -- [37]
        nil, -- [38]
        40, -- [39]
        148, -- [40]
        20, -- [41]
        46, -- [42]
        45, -- [43]
        23, -- [44]
        18, -- [45]
        5, -- [46]
        8, -- [47]
        2, -- [48]
        nil, -- [49]
        nil, -- [50]
        2, -- [51]
        nil, -- [52]
        30, -- [53]
        14, -- [54]
        nil, -- [55]
        3, -- [56]
        [97] = 200,
        [95] = 2,
        [98] = 200,
    },
    ["size"] = 98,
},
```

If you notice, specifically under counts, all but the bottom 3 are the count of the items in that particular bag slot (this is saved data from the Warcraft datastore_containers addon). However, the last three in the list (and this varies), are in this format:

```
[bag slot #] = count
```

How can I reasonable traverse this tree as both the slot number (for example, from index except for the last three (sometimes it's the last 10, last four, etc.. varies), and item count are important.

Ideally, I would like to use something which I can directly embed the source code into my project rather than add another pre-compiled library to the distribution.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually just an issue of parsing the table appropriately. There might be some confusion just because of the way the table is laid out, broken down should be a little easier to read:

```
["Bag-3"] = {
    ["ids"] = {
        2589, -- [1]
        ...
        3356, -- [56]
        [97] = 72988,
        [95] = 82441,
    },
    ["links"] = {
        "|cffffffff|Hitem:2589:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:100:264:0:0:0|h[Linen Cloth]|h|r", -- [1]
        ...
        "|cffffffff|Hitem:3356:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:100:264:0:0:0|h[Kingsblood]|h|r", -- [56]
        [97] = "|cffffffff|Hitem:72988:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:100:264:0:0:0|h[Windwool Cloth]|h|r",
        [95] = "|cffffffff|Hitem:82441:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:100:264:0:0:0|h[Bolt of Windwool Cloth]|h|r",
    },
    ["counts"] = {
        51, -- [1]
        ...
        3, -- [56]
        [97] = 200,
        [95] = 2,
    },
    ["size"] = 98,
},
```

First, a comment in Lua is marked by a `--`, so the lines that end with `-- [X]` are just comments denoting that `[X]` is the specific index (in `n+1`) in the array and the value before the `,` is the value at that index in the array.

So if there's no value associated with an index, it's value will default to `null` (or `nil` in Lua). The lines that don't have comments and explicitly specify the index (e.g. `[97] = 72988,`) are explicit setters.

The table is saved so that congruent values have their index as comments (no need to explicitly state the index), and since the table's congruent values stop at `56` (in this example), then any values after must be explicitly stated and assigned, which is why you'll see something like `3356, -- [56]` followed by `[97] = 72988,`; the value for `[97]` must be explicitly set since there's nothing between it and `[56]`, as well why you'll see some values out of order.

If each "bag" will have the same exact layout (not necessarily same values, but same "table" layout), then you could parse this using a class (no need for external libraries), making note to ensure the `["size"]` property is utilized, example:

```
class Bag
{
    public string Name = string.Empty;
    public int Size = 0;

    public List<int?> Counts = new List<int?>();
    public List<int?> IDs = new List<int?>();
    public List<string> Links = new List<string>();

    public Bag() { }

    public static Bag Parse(string input)
    {
        Bag bag = new Bag();
        int? iv = null;
        int idx = input.IndexOf("[\"") + 2;
        bag.Name = input.Substring(idx, input.IndexOf("\"]") - idx);
        idx = input.IndexOf("[\"size\"] = ") + "[\"size\"] = ".Length; // len;
        bag.Size = int.Parse(input.Substring(idx, input.Substring(idx).IndexOf(",")));

        foreach (object val in GetVals("ids", input, bag.Size)) {
            iv = null;
            if (val != null && val.ToString() != "nil") {
                iv = int.Parse(val.ToString());
            }
            bag.IDs.Add(iv);
        }

        foreach (object val in GetVals("links", input, bag.Size)) {
            bag.Links.Add((string)val);
        }

        foreach (object val in GetVals("counts", input, bag.Size)) {
            iv = null;
            if (val != null && val.ToString() != "nil") {
                iv = int.Parse(val.ToString());
            }
            bag.Counts.Add(iv);
        }
        return bag;
    }

    private static List<object> GetVals(string id, string input, int size)
    {
        List<object> list = new List<object>();
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) { list.Add(null); }
        string tmp, ival = string.Format("[\"{0}\"] = {{", id);
        string[] tsplit = null;
        int len = ival.Length;
        int idx = input.IndexOf(ival) + len;
        foreach (string val in input.Substring(idx, input.Substring(idx).IndexOf("}")).Split('\n')) {
            tmp = val.Trim();
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tmp)) { continue; }
            tsplit = tmp.Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            if (tsplit.Length == 2) {
                int i = (int.Parse((((tsplit[1].Replace("-", "")).Replace("[", "")).Replace("]", "")).Trim()) - 1);
                list[i] = tsplit[0].Trim();
            } else {
                int i = (int.Parse((tsplit[0].Substring(0, tsplit[0].IndexOf("=")).Replace("[", "")).Replace("]", "").Trim()) - 1);
                list[i] = tsplit[0].Substring(tsplit[0].IndexOf("=") + 1).Trim();
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

Then to use: `Bag b = Bag.Parse(bagTableValue);`

This is a more simplistic example and you could use other methods (like `RegEx`), but it's more to illustrate how to parse the table.

Hope that can help.